# Unicode character issue while reading from csv file

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, unicode

In my program, i read the content from csv file then display in UILabel.

What is my problem is Unicode character not working while read it from file.

Suppose i do the code like this.

```
NSString *cubedSymbol = @"10\u00B3";

[label setText:cubedSymbol ];
```

> Output 10³

But same text @"10\u00B3" i read from the file and set it to label.

> output 10\u00B3

Comment: `\uxxxx` only has special meaning at compile time, not runtime. Just put the actual character in the CSV file.

Comment: What are you using to read the CSV file? See something like https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser (specially the sanitizesFields option)